# How to create external links to knowledge base in eGroupware?

Tags: php

I have installed the latest version of egroupware (16.1).  When I connect and use the `phpbrain` or knowledge base application, I cannot use `open in new tab` [navigator's] context menu.

When a new windows is opened, the corresponding knowledge base article is not displayed, instead I get an "Empty" instance of the "Knowledge base" tab.

How can I get a external link that point to an article of the knowledge base?

Comment: Please add the links from the source

Comment: https://github.com/EGroupware/egroupware ? https://www.egroupware.org